# I am getting object has no attribute update in my Django Website

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a crud application and would like to update the items. I have checked some solutions online which explains that the .update method can't be used like this but for only a queryset. I don't know how to update the information manually. Thanks

views.py

```
def UpdateReservation(request, pk):
    table_exists = Reservation.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = ReservationForm(instance=table_exists)
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST['table']:

            request.POST = request.POST.copy()

            table_exists = Reservation.objects.get(id=pk)

            try:
                if table_exists:
                    time = form['time']
                    people = form['people']
                    comment = form['comment']
                    date_reserved = form['date_reserved']
                    email = form['email']
                    phone = form['phone']
                    first_name = form['first_name']

                    resrv = table_exists.update(email=email, first_name=first_name, people=people, time=time, date_reserved=date_reserved, comment=comment, table=table_exists)
                    resrv.save()
                    messages.success(request, "you have successfully edited.")
                    return redirect(request.path)
                else:
                    messages.error(request, "Unable to edit.")
                    return redirect(request.path)


            except Exception as e:
                messages.error(request, "Unknown error" + str(e))
                return redirect(request.path)
                
    context = {"form":form}
    return render(request, "dashboard/super/admin/update_reserve.html", context)
```

After trying that, it returns the error, `Unknown error'Reservation' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: If you are using `form`, then why aren't you validating the form? What if there is invalid data in the form?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to validate the form and update the individual fields with respective values and then save the object. The view should be as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def UpdateReservation(request, pk):
    table_exists = get_object_or_404(Reservation, id=pk)
    form = ReservationForm(instance=table_exists)
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST, instance=table_exists)
        if form.is_valid():
            time = form['time']
            people = form['people']
            comment = form['comment']
            date_reserved = form['date_reserved']
            email = form['email']
            phone = form['phone']
            first_name = form['first_name']

            table_exists.email = email
            table_exists.first_name = first_name
            table_exists.people = people
            table_exists.time = time
            table_exists.date_reserved = date_reserved
            table_exists.comment = comment
            table_exists.save()
            messages.success(request, "you have successfully edited.")
            return redirect(request.path)
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Unable to edit.")
            return redirect(request.path)
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "dashboard/super/admin/update_reserve.html", context)
```

Comment: I have treid this Sir, i get the error "Cannot assign "1": "Reservation.table" must be a "Tables" instance."

Comment: Post your `models.py` containing `Reservation` and `Tables` model in the question.

Comment: Also, post your `forms.py` where you have defined your forms.

Answer (score 0):

You should use model like this:

```
table_exists = Reservation.objects.get(id=pk)
table_exists.email = email
table_exists.first_name = first_name
table_exists.people = people
table_exists.time = time
table_exists.date_reserved = date_reserved
table_exists.comment = comment
table_exists.table = table_exists
table_exists.save()
```

Comment: I get this error after that Sir, "Unknown errorCannot assign "<Reservation: Hamza >": "Reservation.table" must be a "Tables" instance."